# 7zip batch file does not include extension Why?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, zip, 7-zip

I found the below batch file and it works fine but I need the code to add the extension to the final zip file. I am sure this is a simple question but I have tried everything.

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
rem 7z.exe path
set sevenzip=
if "%sevenzip%"=="" if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe" set sevenzip=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe
if "%sevenzip%"=="" if exist "%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe" set sevenzip=%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe
if "%sevenzip%"=="" echo 7-zip not found&pause&exit
echo %~dp1
echo %~x1
for %%a in (*%extension%) do "%sevenzip%" a "%%~na.zip" "%%a"
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: `%%~na.zip`, it should be `%%~fa.zip`

Simplifying things a bit, suppose I have the following files in my directory:

- foo.en.pdf
- bar.en.pdf

Issue this on the command line:

`for %a in (*.*) do 7z a "%~fa.zip" "%a"`

This results in two Zip archives:

- foo.en.pdf.zip
- bar.en.pdf.zip

Comment: I knew a superuser would know the answer. Thanks a lot.